# Javascript Pie Ch

Tags: javascript, java, css, pie-chart, canvasjs

I'm trying to customise a pie-chart from here:
https://canvasjs.com/jquery-charts/pie-chart-index-data-label-inside/

The code I have used is below, with my edits:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

var options = {
exportEnabled: true,
animationEnabled: true,
title:{
    text: "Operational Excellence"
},
data: [{
    type: "pie",
    showInLegend: false,
    indexLabel: "{name}",
    indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
    dataPoints: [
        { y: 16.66666666666667, name: "Innovation" },
        { y: 16.66666666666667, name: "Leadership <br> Behaviours" },
        { y: 16.66666666666667, name: "Continuous Improvement" },
        { y: 16.66666666666667, name: "Employee Engagement" },
        { y: 16.66666666666667, name: "Exceed Customer Expectations"},
        { y: 16.66666666666667, name: "High Reliability" }
    ]
}]
};
$("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart(options);

}
 </script>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to make it look like this:
https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56683787841abadb3a833983/t/5aad434c88251b56303ee2b4/1521304417200/chart.jpg?format=1000w

How do I stick a html break "< b r >" within the dataPoints and is there a chart library around that will do more like the image above?

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: What does this have to do with `java`? Java != JavaScript. Says so right there in the tooltips of both.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Tags are not supported in [indexLabels](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/labels-index-labels/) as of now. However you can use [indexLabelMaxWidth](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/indexlabelmaxwidth/) to achieve the same. Please check the code below.

```js
var options = {
    exportEnabled: true,
    animationEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: "Operational Excellence"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "pie",
        showInLegend: false,
        indexLabel: "{name}",
        indexLabelMaxWidth: 100,
        indexLabelPlacement: "inside",
        dataPoints: [
            { y: 16.66666666666667, name: "Innovation" },
            { y: 16.66666666666667, name: "Leadership Behaviours" },
            { y: 16.66666666666667, name: "Continuous Improvement" },
            { y: 16.66666666666667, name: "Employee Engagement" },
            { y: 16.66666666666667, name: "Exceed Customer Expectations"},
            { y: 16.66666666666667, name: "High Reliability" }
        ]
    }]
};

$("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart(options);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```